# Spring MVC Ajax Response Failing

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am relatively new to Spring MVC and have been searching for a bit and haven't found an answer to what I am doing wrong and would love some StackOverflow help.

I have built a comments functionality popup where users can added comments to records.  When I submit the record with just a regular comment, everything comes back as expected and the new comment gets added.  When I submit with a #tag, I end up creating a separate collection to break apart the tag.  When I create the tag collection and return the object, I get the error message "**getOutputStream() has already been called for this response**".  What could be so different by adding the collection ?

Here is my ajax method:

```
function saveCommentViaAjax() {
        $("#add_comment").prop("disabled", true);
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/comments/add",
            data :  $('#commentsForm').serialize(),
            dataType : 'json',
            timeout : 100000,
            success : function(data) {
                commentVal = "<div class=\"comments_box\" style=\"width:100% !important;margin:10px 0px !important;\">";
                commentVal += "<div class=\"comments_header\">";
                commentVal += "<div class=\"comments_by\" style=\"float:left;\">" + data.createdBy + "</div>";
                commentVal += "<div class=\"comments_date\" style=\"float:right;\">" + data.fancyTime + "</div>";
                commentVal += "</div>";
                commentVal += "<div class=\"clearfix comments_top\"></div>";
                commentVal += "<div class=\"comments_text\">" + data.noteRaw + "</div>";
                commentVal += "<div class=\"comment_tags\"><strong>Tags: </strong>" + data.tagList + "</div>";
                commentVal += "</div>";

                $("#commentsGroup").append(commentVal);                 
               $("#add_comment").prop("disabled", false);
                $("#commentCount").text(data.noteCount);
                $("#comment").val("");
                $("#comment").focus();
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $("#add_comment").prop("disabled", false);
            },
            done : function(e) {
                console.log("DONE");
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="add", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody MetaNote addComment(CommentsWrapper commentsCollection) {    

    if (commentsCollection.getComment().length() > 0){
        UserProfile user = (UserProfile) session().getAttribute(Utility.AUTHORIZED_USER);
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        MetaNote mn = new MetaNote();

        mn.setNoteRaw(commentsCollection.getComment());
        mn.setActive(true);
        mn.setCreatedBy(user.getFullName());

        //Parse out Tags
        Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("#(\\S+)");
        Matcher matcher = MY_PATTERN.matcher(commentsCollection.getComment());
        while (matcher.find()) {
            MetaTag mt = new MetaTag();
            mt.setTag(matcher.group(1));
            mt.setMetaNote(mn);
            mt.setActive(true);
            mn.getMetaTags().add(mt);
        }

        processMetaNote(mn);
        return mn;
    }
    return null;
}
```

and finally here is my page code:

```
<div>
            <form:form enctype="utf8" action="/provider/spring/comments/addComment" method="POST" id="commentsForm" modelAttribute="commentsWrapper">
                <form:textarea path="comment" id="comment" rows="3" cssClass="textarea_style" cssStyle="width:100% !important; padding: 0 10px !important;"/>
                <div style="float:right;margin-top:2px;">
                    <form:button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" id="add_comment" value="ADD">submit</form:button>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </form:form>
        </div>
        <div>
        <span id="commentCount">${commentsWrapper.noteCount}</span> Comment(s):
        </div>
        <!-- Show Existing Comments  -->
        <div id="commentsGroup" style="height: 400px; overflow: scroll;">
            <!-- Start Loop Here -->
            <c:forEach var="mNote" items="${commentsWrapper.metaNotes}">   
        <!-- Outside Border -->
            <div class="comments_box" style="width:100% !important;margin:10px 0px !important;">
                <div class="comments_header">
                    <div class="comments_by" style="float:left;">
                    <!-- Who said it -->
                    ${mNote.createdBy}

                    </div>
                    <div class="comments_date" style="float:right;">
                    <!-- When they said it -->
                    ${mNote.fancyTime}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix comments_top"></div>
                <div class="comments_text">
                    ${mNote.noteRaw}
                </div>
                <div class="comment_tags">
                    <strong>Tags:</strong> ${mNote.tagList}
                </div>
            </div>
            </c:forEach>  

        <!-- End of Loop -->
        </div>
```

As always, any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you add the code of `processMetaNote()`?

Comment: @lucumt The processMetaNote is just the save method and it is using hibernate.  It saves everything perfectly each time with or without the tags added.  The adding of the tags for some reason causes the error when it call the return statement.